# I cannot view the map on my android using react-native maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to use a map in my app using react-native-maps. First it gives me this error

```
"Could not find method compileOnly() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler."
```

Then i change the my code in `node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/build.gradle` as follows

**previous code**

```
  compileOnly() "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
  implementation" com.google.android.gms:play-services- 
    base:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
  implementation" com.google.android.gms:play-services- 
    maps:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
  implementation "com.google.maps.android:android-maps- 
    utils:$androidMapsUtilsVersion"
```

**Changes made**

```
provided "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services- 
   base:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services- 
     maps:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
compile "com.google.maps.android:android-maps- 
     utils:$androidMapsUtilsVersion"
```

Then the error was gone and but still the map is not loaded into my app 
How can i solve this.

Comment: did you add/edit all the steps given in this : https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

Comment: yes but map is not visible in my app

Comment: How can  i fix this

Comment: is it necessary to have the gradle version 3

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that change nodes modules is a good idea. You should probably adapt your configuration to the library, could you paste your gradle conf files?
android/build.gradle and the root one.